# relations with 4 tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have four tables as follows.

| Services_cats | Session_pat | Invoice_item | Invoice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id | id |
| name | services_cat_id | service_id | code |
|  | patient_id | invoice_id | discount |

I need to have relations among them with one Eloquent query in Laravel. Below is what I have reached so far; I used many-to-many relations in the invoice table.

```
public function invoice_item()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Session_pat::class, 'invoice_items', "invoice_id", 
    "service_id", "id", "id");
}
```

And I used this code to access the four tables.

```
$status4 = Invoice::select('id')->with(['invoice_item' => function ($q){
    $q->select('id', 'services_cat_id')
        ->with(['service_cat' => function ($q) {$q->select('id as myid', 'name');}])
            ;}])
            ->where('id', 122)->get();
```

but I get this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in
> field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `id`, `services_cat_id`,
> `invoice_items`.`invoice_id` as `pivot_invoice_id`,
> `invoice_items`.`service_id` as `pivot_service_id` from `session_pats`
> inner join `invoice_items` on `session_pats`.`id` =
> `invoice_items`.`service_id` where `invoice_items`.`invoice_id` in
> (122) order by `id` desc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should Specific The Table Name, WHen Using Same Column Name In Query.

Rule: tableName.column EX: invoiceTable.id

```
$status4 = Invoice::select('TableName.id')->with(['invoice_item' => function ($q){
            $q->select('TableName.id', 'services_cat_id')
                ->with(['service_cat' => function ($q) {$q->select('TableName.id as myid', 'name');}])
                ;}])
            ->where('TableName.id', 122)->get();
```